# rolling joins on multiple matches

Tags: r, join, data.table

Hey I am not sure if i fully understand the rolling join solution specially when it comes to duplicate entries in table.

Here is a sample data :

```
new <- data.table( date = as.POSIXct( c( "2016-03-01 12:20:00", "2016-03-01 12:20:00", "2016-04-02 12:20:00" ) ), data.new = c( "sample1","sample2","sample3" ) )
new
old <- data.table( date = as.POSIXct( c( "2016-03-02 12:20:00", "2016-03-07 12:20:00", "2016-04-02 12:20:00", "2015-03-02 12:20:00" ) ), data.old = c( "a","b","c","d" ) )
old
setkey( new, date )
setkey( old, date )
new[old,roll=-Inf]
```

The output looks like :

```
                       date data.new data.old
1: 2015-03-02 12:20:00  sample1        d
2: 2016-03-02 12:20:00  sample3        a
3: 2016-03-07 12:20:00  sample3        b
4: 2016-04-02 12:20:00  sample3        c
```

I am getting the match to work properly except for the case of data.old 'd'.
Since table new has first two time stamps similar, roll is just able to map to the first occurrence ideally i wanted a duplicated row for data.old "d" with data.new column as "sample2"

```
                      date data.new data.old
  new: 2015-03-02 12:20:00  sample2        d
    1: 2015-03-02 12:20:00  sample1        d
    2: 2016-03-02 12:20:00  sample3        a
    3: 2016-03-07 12:20:00  sample3        b
    4: 2016-04-02 12:20:00  sample3        c
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
on <- old[new, roll = Inf, .(x.date, data.new, data.old)]
no <- new[old, roll = -Inf]

unique(rbindlist(list(on, no)))
```

gives:

```
                x.date data.new data.old
1: 2015-03-02 12:20:00  sample1        d
2: 2015-03-02 12:20:00  sample2        d
3: 2016-04-02 12:20:00  sample3        c
4: 2016-03-02 12:20:00  sample3        a
5: 2016-03-07 12:20:00  sample3        b
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.. I am looking at the nearest time stamp match so i used rolling join, so i just  want to match it to the nearest timestamp and if there is multiple nearest time stamp, i want to duplicate rows in that case(so i just want two rows for "d", as `sample 1` and `sample 2` are the closest). Using non equi join i would get all timestamps that are greater or less than the timestamps i am joing to() in your solutions case all the greater ones.